# Nature of spontaneous reactions

Tags: thermodynamics

The definition of spontaneous process states that "A spontaneous process is an irreversible process and maybe reversed by some external agency"

So, can we say that all spontaneous reactions are irreversible reactions under the absence of some external force?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A spontaneous reaction, as contrasted with a non-spontaneous reaction, is a reaction quantified by a negative free energy change. A reaction is said to be spontaneous if it occurs without being driven by an outside force. So, we can say:  In any spontaenous process, the path between the reactants and products is irreversible